# Issue with parallel execution using Ruby language on Mac machine

Tags: automated-testing

We have a requirement for running multiple suites in parallel in our software testing services.

Below are the 3 approaches that I have tried so far:

1. Added parallel_tests in Gemfile.
2. Added 'require parallel_tests' in rake file
3. Created 02 nodes and also created a Grid Console for execution of both the nods in parallel

Result: Only one node gets executed successfully instead of executing both of them in parallel.

Configurations used are:

Language: Ruby 2.3

Mac: 10.2.3 version

Rpsec, rake file framework structure

Answer (score 1):

There are a few gems for running RSpec in parallel:

https://github.com/willbryant/parallel_rspec

https://github.com/yuku-t/parallel-rspec

https://github.com/bicarbon8/rspec-parallel

RSpec also provides filtering options ([doc here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/file/Filtering.md)). With that, you can do `rspec --tag module_X`.

Using this feature, you could make a native parallelization:
`rspec -t module_Y & rspec -t module_X & rspec -t module_Z`

You would have to merge the reports somehow, though.